# Laravel 5 form with file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have a table like this:

```
Schema::create('partners', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('id');
$table->binary('image');
$table->string('name');
$table->string('link');
$table->timestamps();
});
```

Then, after validation, I need to add data from forms, defined as this: 
`{{Form::file('image')}}` I tried this way:

```
public function newPartner(Request $request) {

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
'name' => 'required',
'link' => 'required'
]);
if ($validator->fails()) {
 return redirect('partners/create')->withErrors($validator);
}
Partner::create($request->all());

return redirect('/');
}
```

But it doesn't fill the binary field with the uploaded image.
How can I achieve this? 
Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Why are you using `binary` field as the column type for image column ??

Comment: Do you really need to put image as a binary in database? I strongly recommend you to store only file name of the image in database.